# No error in console but unable to view Admin module of Broadleaf Commericial Edition in the browser

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am using BroadLeaf B2B Commercial Edition version 5.2.2-GA, I have got no error while executing the below commands as per specified in ReadMe.md

> mvn clean install
>
> cd admin
>
> mvn spring-boot:run

But there is no page is getting displayed in the below urls

> https://localhost:8444/admin
>
> http://localhost:8081/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Multi-Tenant version of Broadleaf, you will either need to set up DNSMasq to go to map URLs to localhost or set up /etc/hosts with either the `test` or `global` subdomains (which are the default multi-tenant sites):

```
127.0.0.1 test.blc.dev
127.0.0.1 global.blc.dev
```

If this is the case you should also see a warning message in your logs about not being able to find a site.

Comment: I have tried the same still, I am getting the same error, also how can configure log4j in a Spring boot application